# How to delete a pulse post in Linkedin?

Tags: linkedin

I have written [an article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/nextservices-great-place-work-zameer-ansari?trk=prof-post) on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/).

I do know how to update (and publish) it however, I'm not able to find a way to delete it. Does anyone know the work around?

Answer (score 1):

From [Help Center](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5263):

> LinkedIn Pulse can't be removed from the homepage. Learn how to [customize the channels and Influencers you follow](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5008/ft/eng).

[Here is a discussion](http://community.linkedin.com/questions/142160/removing-pulse-news.html) about it. It says install Adblock Plus and use filter.

> New Filters for AdBlock Plus:

```
linkedin.com##LI[id="today-news-wrapper"][class="feed-item today-news-el tod-wrpr feed-item-insert"]
linkedin.com##LI[id="today-news-wrapper"][class="feed-item today-news-el tod-wrpr"]
linkedin.com##.linkedin-recommend-pulse
```

Comment: Sorr, for being too late :( How does it deletes the [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/nextservices-great-place-work-zameer-ansari)?

Comment: _LinkedIn Pulse can't be removed from the homepage._

Comment: Agreed, I wanted to delete the article I written. not *LinkedIn Pulse*